# Android ServerSocket strange exception

Tags: java, android, serversocket

When the code reaches that line:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

the code is

```
package com.kworks.org.tower_offense_game;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
/**
* Created by User on 27.4.2016 г..
*/
public class Server extends Thread{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket server;

    public Server(int port)throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(100000);

    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {

        }
    }
    public static void startServer()
    {
        Server t=null;

        try {
            t = new Server(12905);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(t!=null) {
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

the application gives that exception:
04-29 09:04:40.467 24726-24726/? W/ClassFailureStapler:

failed to install class failure stapler; proceeding
                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: could not hook fn dvmInitClass: crit: tgt=409a1964{0} pos=409a1ddc{1144} cr=[409a196c,409a196c){8}
                                                            at com.facebook.common.dextricks.DalvikInternals.setClassInitFailureHook(Native Method)
                                                            at com.facebook.common.dextricks.ClassFailureStapler.install(web_view_number:31)
                                                            at com.facebook.common.dextricks.ClassFailureStapler.tryInstall(web_view_number:39)
                                                            at com.facebook.katana.app.FacebookApplication.c(}:218)
                                                            at com.facebook.base.app.DelegatingApplication.attachBaseContext(|NO:113)
                                                            at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:147)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1053)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1037)
                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4613)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Which line of code are you talking about?

Comment: When the "ServerSocket" is created.

 When i make it a comment it runs correctly

Comment: In what or from where you you use that code line?

Comment: I updated the article with the code
@greenapps

Comment: Think you should move that statement to `run()`.